# How to Configure My sql in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: magnolia

I am new to magnolia cms.

I am working on an application now it has configured with Jack-rabbit.
Now I want to replace the Jack-rabbit  with Mysql.

How can I configure My sql to the the Magnolia cms.

Can any one have any idea how can this be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't replace Jackrabbit with MySQL. Using MySQL instead of Derby does not replace Jackrabbit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **replace** Jackrabbit[1], you can only configure it to store its data in MySQL instead of the default Derby DB. You can find a pretty comprehensive HOWTO at https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Magnolia+CMS+with+MySQL

[1] Actually, you can, although not directly with a database, but with another JCR implementation (CRX, ModeShape). Anyway, this is an expert topic.

Comment: hi @jozef Now I am able to change my configuration to MYSQL but I am getting exception while publishing content from author to public Instance. Is there any way to store the activation key permanently in order to publish.

Comment: @student-17 Would you mind to copy the exception here? We do not have access to your system.

Have you read https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Activation+security especially the Troubleshooting section?

Comment: Anyway, I highly recommend to go through the [Magnolia Academy](https://academy.magnolia-cms.com/) to get the proper Magnolia "mindset".

Comment: @student-17 If you are getting an exception during publishing, then it has nothing to do with the mysql configuration probably, but the Configuration: server > activation > subscribers > ... > URL is probably configured incorrectly (maybe wrong url/port).